# How to implement Postfix increment operator

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

I've learned:
A user defined postfix increment operator should return a const object to behave like a fundamental arithmetic type:

```
int i = 0;
i++ = 42; // error, i++ is pr-value
++i = 42; // ok, ++i is l-value
```

so for class Widget it should be declared like

```
const Widget operator++(int);
...
Widget w1, w2;
w1++ = w2; // error, fine, same as i++ = 42
```

without const, it would compile. But with this in place, it's not possible,
to call

```
void f(Widget&&);
f(w1++); // error, invalid initialization of Widget&& from expression const Widget
```

what's a pitty, cause w1++ is an r-value expression and it's constness has no impact, cause it's a temporary, isn't it?

Now, how should operator++(int) be declared?
Thanks for giving advice.

Comment: This is how these operators should be declared http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A user defined postfix increment operator should return a const object to behave like a fundamental arithmetic type:

Returning `const`-qualified class types is not generally recommended in C++11. As you noticed, it prevents move operations from being used. To behave like a fundamental arithmetic type, a simpler approach is disabling the `=` operator on rvalues.

```
struct S {
  S &operator=(const S &) & = default;
  S &operator=(S &&) & = default;
};
S f() { return {}; }
int main() {
  S s;
  s = s; // okay
  s = f(); // okay
  f() = s; // error
}
```

With this, you can declare `Widget operator++(int);`, reject `w1++ = w2;`, but allow `f(w1++);`.

Answer (score 0):

`Widget operator++(int);` is the standard definition.

Declaring functions which return by value but also return `const`,  the function writer is trying to restrict what the function consumer does with the function.

Personally I never do this, it's just an unnecessary constraint and causes problems exactly like you show in this example.  But other people feel that it's worth the "price" of disallowing `f(w1++)` in order to get a compiler diagnostic about `w1++ = w2;` which is likely to be a logic error.  It's a matter of opinion and coding style really.